# React-native FlatList not rerendering row when props change

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

I'm having an issue with the new FlatList component. Specifically, it does not rerender it's rows, even though props that the row is dependent on changes.

---

The FlatList docs says that:

> This is a PureComponent which means that it will not re-render if
>   props remain shallow- equal. Make sure that everything your renderItem
>   function depends on is passed as a prop that is not === after updates,
>   otherwise your UI may not update on changes. This includes the data
>   prop and parent component state.

**THE QUESTION**

However, seeing as I change an ID of the selectedCategory item - the prop that should indicate whether the row is 'selected' or not - I believe that the props should rerender. Am I mistaken?

I checked the 'componentWillReceiveProps' methods of both the list and row components, and the list receives the update just fine, but the row's lifecycle method is never called.

If I include a random, useless boolean state value in the list component, and switch it back and forth when the props update, it works - but I don't know why?

```
state = { updated: false };

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState(oldstate => ({
    updated: !oldstate.updated,
  }));
}

<FlatList
  data={this.props.items.allAnimalCategories.edges}
  renderItem={this._renderRow}
  horizontal={true}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.node.id}
  randomUpdateProp={this.state.updated}
/>
```

---

**THE CODE**

The structure of my code is this: I have a container component with all the logic and state, which contains a FlatList component (presentational, no state), which again contains a custom presentational row.

```
Container
  Custom list component that includes the FlatList component
  (presentational, stateless) and the renderRow method
    Custom row (presentational, stateless)
```

The container includes this component:

```
 <CustomList
   items={this.props.viewer}
   onCategoryChosen={this._onCategoryChosen}
   selectedCategory={this.state.report.selectedCategory}
 />
```

CustomList:

```
class CustomList extends Component {
  _renderRow = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <CustomListRow
        item={item.node}
        selectedCategory={this.props.selectedCategory}
        onPressItem={this.props.onCategoryChosen}
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={_styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.items.categories.edges}
          renderItem={this._renderRow}
          horizontal={true}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.node.id}
          randomUpdateProp={this.state.updated}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

}

(data comes from Relay)

Finally the row:

```
render() {
    const idsMatch = this.props.selectedCategory.id == this.props.item.id;
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onItemPressed}>
        <View style={_styles.root}>
          <View style={[
              _styles.container,
              { backgroundColor: this._getBackgroundColor() },
            ]}>
            {idsMatch &&
              <Image
                style={_styles.icon}
                source={require('./../../res/img/asd.png')}
              />}
            {!idsMatch &&
              <Image
                style={_styles.icon}
                source={require('./../../res/img/dsa.png')}
              />}
            <Text style={_styles.text}>
              {capitalizeFirstLetter(this.props.item.name)}
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={_styles.bottomView}>
            <View style={_styles.greyLine} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
```

The row is not that interesting, but I included it to show that it is entirely stateless and dependent on it's parents props.

The state is updated like so:

```
_onCategoryChosen = category => {
    var oldReportCopy = this.state.report;
    oldReportCopy.selectedCategory = category;
    this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state, { report: oldReportCopy }));
  };
```

State looks like this:

```
state = {
    ...
    report: defaultStateReport,
  };

const defaultStateReport = {
  selectedCategory: {
    id: 'some-long-od',
    name: '',
  },
  ...
};
```

---

Comment: Your reference to the docs solved my issue.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The problem here lies within the fact that

1. You are mutating an existing slice of state instead of creating a mutated copy

---

```
_onCategoryChosen = category => {
    var oldReportCopy = this.state.report; // This does not create a copy!
    oldReportCopy.selectedCategory = category;
    this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state, { report: oldReportCopy }));
};
```

This should be

```
_onCategoryChosen = category => {
    var oldReportCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state.report);
    oldReportCopy.selectedCategory = category;
    // setState handles partial updates just fine, no need to create a copy
    this.setState({ report: oldReportCopy });
};
```

---

2. The props of FlatList remain the same, your `_renderRow` function may rely on the `selectedCategory` prop which does change (If not for the first mistake), but the FlatList component does not know about that. To solve this, use the [`extraData`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata) prop.

   ```
    <FlatList
      data={this.props.items.categories.edges}
      renderItem={this._renderRow}
      horizontal={true}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.node.id}
      extraData={this.props.selectedCategory}
    />
   ```

Answer (score 40):

Simply you can solve this problem passing **props** to **extraData** in **flat list** component like this,

```
  <FlatList
    data={this.props.data}
    extraData={this.props}
    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
  />
```

Answer (score 9):

In my case I just made a simple mistake when using `keyExtractor`

I changed

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
```

To

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
```

I was seeing a strange effect after filtering my list where the props of the filtered components were being rendered in place of the new component's props, I believe it was because I was using the index of the array rather than the unique key associated with the item in the list.

Comment: I have never facepalmed myself that hard, when I realised what I'd being doing. Don't use index :)

Comment: Never use index again, it helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: This is what worked for me, as well! Was adjusting someone else's code, and couldn't figure out why it wouldn't update. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Nimelrian. Also, If your state is an Array you could create an Array Object from the state by doing:

```
 var oldReportCopy = Object.assign([], this.state.report);
```

Then use the .push() method to add your new object to it like this:

```
oldReportCopy.push(selectedCategory);
```

you can then set this new Array Object back to state:

```
this.setState({ report: oldReportCopy });
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this won't be the case for anyone else but I realized I was only having trouble when the array of items being rendered by the FlatList became empty. In my case I just needed to not render the FlatList at all, and instead render a different View in its place, and that of course fixed my issue with it "not re-rendering".

Answer (score 0):

Look at line #4

```js
_onCategoryChosen = category => {
    var oldReportCopy = this.state.report;
    oldReportCopy.selectedCategory = category;
    this.setState({ report: [...oldReportCopy] }); // Notice this line
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

this wasn't working for me

```
       setTabData(tabD);
```

and this worked for me

```
      setTabData([...tabD]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In react hooks you can do something like this:

```
const onPressLeaderSelect = (item, index) => {
    let oldMemberCopy = Object.assign([], teamMemberArr);  //'teamMemberArr' is local state
    let objIndex = oldMemberCopy.findIndex((obj => obj.teamLeader == 1));
    oldMemberCopy[objIndex].teamLeader = 0
    oldMemberCopy[index].teamLeader = 1
    console.log('onPressLeaderSelect', oldMemberCopy)
    setteamMemberArr(oldMemberCopy)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be helpful `FlatList` [code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/de09bd3b840908ac5cdbf229546a9f8b530b4eb2/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.js#L126)

```
/**
 * Multiple columns can only be rendered with `horizontal={false}` and will zig-zag like a `flexWrap` layout.
 * Items should all be the same height - masonry layouts are not supported.
 */
numColumns?: number | undefined;
```