# React Native Flatlist not rerender

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-saga, react-native-flatlist

Im using Flatlist in my React Native application. My application will fetch data from server and show on FlatList. Props/State are updated via Redux and Redux-saga

Now I get an issue that flat list not update/not call renderItem after data is fetched from server. I try set extraData props (like others suggestion [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44278526/react-native-flatlist-not-rerendering-row-when-props-change), [document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#extradata)) and make sure Flatlist's size is larger than zero but no luck. I also try to set some predefined data and flatlist displays it perfectly but not update after new data comes. I did check that _listView function is called after data updated but _listViewRenderItem is not.

Below is my pieces of code. I will very appreciate any helps. Thanks

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   var index = nextProps.bintype_ids.indexOf(nextProps.bin.id)
   if (index != -1) {
      _data = nextProps.wastetypes[index]
   } else {
      _data = { allow : [], not_allow : []}
   }

   const newState = {
      index : this.state.index + 1,
      change : !this.state.change,
      wastetypes : _data
   }

   this.setState(newState)
}

_listViewRenderItem(item) {
   return (
     <BinGuideListItem item={item} />
   )
}

_listView(data) {

  return (
      <FlatList style={css.segmentList}
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {this._listViewRenderItem(item)}}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this._renderSeparator}
          extraData = {this.state}
      />
  );
}

render(){
  return (
    <View>
      <SegmentControl
         values={['Allow', 'Not Allowed']}
         tabContents={[
            this._listView(this.state.wastetypes.allow),
            this._listView(this.state.wastetypes.not_allow),    
         ]}
         style={{
            container: css.segmentContainer,
            contentContainer : css.contentContainer,
            tabText: css.segmentTabText,
            tab: css.segmentTab,
         }}
         colorsByTab={[
            common.COLOR_BIN_GUIDE_ALLOWED,
            common.COLOR_BIN_GUIDE_NOT_ALLOWED
         ]}
         borderRadius={0.1}
      />
    </View>
  )  
 }
}
```

Comment: did you checked the length of `data`?

Comment: I did check. Data is fine. I also copy data from server to hard coded data and Flatlist render perfectly

Comment: is your `data` is valid json/array? if possible please create a code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Data pass to flatlist will be like this:`[{"title":"Lorem ipsum dolor 2","id":"5","bintype_id":"1","wastetype_id":"2","is_allow":"1"},{"title":"Lorem ipsum dolor 3","id":"6","bintype_id":"1","wastetype_id":"3","is_allow":"1"},{"title":"Lorem ipsum dolor 4","id":"7","bintype_id":"1","wastetype_id":"4","is_allow":"1"}]`

Comment: instead of `this._listViewRenderItem(item)` can you just render `item.title` and check whether it works

Comment: @AravindS I tried but it also does not work :(

Comment: which means the problem is with `data={data}`..it btw where is `data` in your code. please create a sandbox.

Comment: @AravindS yeah. I will try to create a code sandbox. Im newbie in React and React Native. Btw, Im confusing how FlatList decide when it should be re-render. Does Flatlist compare data or extraData or both? It is shallow compare or something?

Comment: flatlist re-render can be done in a couple of ways using `extraData` prop or by using setState itself.More find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397803/how-to-re-render-flatlist

Comment: @AravindS Sorry, codesandbox.io seems quite hard for me. I tried with [snack.expo]https://snack.expo.io/B1LdPApmQ . As you can see, the example at Snack works file. Maybe I do wrong with current flow: reducer -> mapStateToProps: map redux state to props -> componentWillReceiveProps: update component state -> render() -> _listView() -> _listViewRenderItem(): not called

Comment: if the expo links works fine means how i can help you>

Comment: @AravindS expo works fine but my code does not :(. Im diving into VirtualizedList to find out problem. Currently, I know that getDerivedStateFromProps not fired after data update.

Comment: `SegmentControl` where does that component come from? any external library

Comment: Change to `renderItem={ ({ item }) => this._listViewRenderItem(item) }`, remove the unwanted curly braces. Return an element. How come this work without returning any element the first time?.

Comment: @RaviRaj `SegmentControl` is [react-native-segment-controller](https://github.com/csath/react-native-segment-controller). About curly braces, it is not a problem at all. Above code works fine with predefined value. I think problem here is that FlatList can not trigger props change. I see when props change, `getDerivedStateFromProps` of `VirtualizedList` not call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After diving into problem and separate my list from my segment control, I figure out that the problem relies on Segment Control. All my list components belong to tabContent state of Segment Control. It seems not work because segment control keeps render old tab contents. So my solution now is that handling props change (when tab contents change) and update tab contents state of Segment Control.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Below code with

```
_data = nextProps.wastetypes[index]
```

**THIS**

```
_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( nextProps.wastetypes[index]));
```